# Accessing the JSON response in the failure block of AFNetworking 2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-services, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

With AFNetworking 2, when you're handling a failure in the failure block, how do you access the content returned from the server? In my case I'm posting to a Rails app that is returning:

> {"number":["is already taken"]}

That's what I get if I use curl like this: `curl -X POST -d "sales_order[number]=12345" http://localserver.dev/api/v1/sales_orders.json`

I'm trying to get the same JSON within AFNetworking 2.  After reading all over SO I managed to get access to some response header information by examining [error userInfo] inside of my failure block.

Does anyone know how I can access the {"number":["is already taken"]} from inside of the failure block?

This is my block currently:

```
failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Sales Order Failure");

    NSDictionary *userInfo = [error userInfo];

    for(NSString *key in [userInfo allKeys]) {
        NSLog(@"%@ - %@", key, [userInfo objectForKey:key]);
    }
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a known design deficiency in AFNetworking 2.x, and has been discussed [here](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/1397) with some workarounds.